# PHP array_multisort

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some difficulties with sorting arrays. I tried with methods SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC but it never works. Even when I put array_multisort anywhere else in the code.

So this is how my arrays looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.13
            [1] => Ships From
            [2] => Russia
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.11
            [1] => Color
            [2] => Green
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.1
            [1] => Size
            [2] => M
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.12
            [1] => Material
            [2] => Flex
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.13
            [1] => Ships From
            [2] => China
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.11
            [1] => Color
            [2] => Red
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.1
            [1] => Size
            [2] => L
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.12
            [1] => Material
            [2] => Cotton
        )

)
```

As you can see I have double [0], and by that value to sort them all.
So my code looks like this:

```
foreach($value['options'] as $key => $option)
            {
                $sort = array();


                $attribude= $this->attribute($option['key']);
               
                $attribute_value= $this->attribude($getAttr->id, $option['value']);

                $collection = array_push($sort, array($attribude->default_order, $attribude->label, $attribute_value->value));

                print_r($sort);
            }
```

I tried to add `array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC);` basically everywhere where I could, but it's never working.
Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: I'd start by sorting out that array structure. I'd also look at the variable names you're using ($attribute, $attribude, etc.) Once the code makes some sense it'll be easier. Where's that data coming from? If it's from a database get that to sort it for you.

Comment: Well yes, data is from database, it only gets order_id, value and label for that attribute. And I can't sort it, because it's firstOrFail method

Comment: Can you post your call to the Model? I believe you should be able to chain an orderby method to findOrFail.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, if you can, restructuring your array before attempting to sort. Below is an example of the restructured array sorted by the number 2 index. You can adjust the index by changing this `$row[2]` like `$row[0]` to sort by the float value of index zero.

```
$array = [
    array(0.13,'Ships From','C'),
    array(0.12,'Ships From','D'),
    array(0.10,'Ships From','B'),
    array(0.14,'Ships From','A'),
];

$a = array();
$b = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $a[$key] = $row[2];
}
array_multisort($a, SORT_ASC, $array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.14
            [1] => Ships From
            [2] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.1
            [1] => Ships From
            [2] => B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.13
            [1] => Ships From
            [2] => C
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.12
            [1] => Ships From
            [2] => D
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

An inline solution:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a[0] <=> $b[0]; });
```

A flagship operator requires PHP 7+, otherwise compare manually. For reverse (DESC) order swap $a with $b.

Comment: it's called spaceship not flagship :D